# iOS ObjC Networking and selectors in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, networking, selector

I'm trying to get image by HTTP using NSURLConnection. I perform selector in background

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadingDaemon) withObject:nil];
```

where I do this

```
NSString *fullImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/%@", baseURL, currentlyLoadingImage];
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullImageURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL];
request.timeoutInterval = 10;
NSURLConnection *newConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I set NSURLConnection' delegate to **self** and implement methods

```
connection:didReceiveResponse:
connection:didReceiveData:
connection:didFailWithError:
connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

Besides, I log every method call and condition branch. But 4 functions as above are never called. Please can you explain me why?

Comment: I suspect the URL you're creating contains special characters without being escaped, so it's invalid.

Comment: What happens if you say `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` at the end of your method?

Comment: Just so you know, a main reason to use the asynchronous loading of NSURLConnection is so that you can do all of this on the main thread and not have to background it.

Comment: 2 H2CO3 - The test URL is "http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png", I check it out :)

2 Kevin - Thanks very much! It's working! :)

2 Carl - Yes, but I have to control connections in background too, because I load a lot of images in background

Answer (score 0):

The NSURLConnection you are creating is performing those operations in the background so there shouldn't be a need to perform it in the background and is the reason its not working for you. You could instead use NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest with your current way of calling your selector or just call that function directly.

Comment: The problem is that I have to run in other thread my ImageLoader class which works like as daemon. And if I perform NSURLConnection request in background, is waiting for reply runs in the same thread as the my daemon?

Comment: I don't think they will affect each other but if they do then run what you have as a synchronous request which will work. You just can't do an asynchronous request that is started in the background.